Is there a way to indicate an affordance is deprecated?
As our API evolves we need to deprecate links and provide new ones with new names.
For links I can achieve this with code like
model.add(
    linkTo(methodOn(...).legacyMethod(...))
            .withRel("linkName")
            .withDeprecation("Deprecated. Use xxx")
);

I can't however find any way to achieve something like this for Affordances. I spent quite a while digging through the framework, accessing the underlying AffordanceModel and Link but couldn't get anything working.
Is there something obvious I'm missing?
Is there no way of indicating that an affordance is going to be phased out/deprecated?
